# Updating the blender simulation by scripts

Tags: python

I was looking around and saw that blender has the python bpy module which can basically touch or do anything within blender.

If I setup a simulation in blender then control it from blender scripts using a python script?

If so is there some sample code to do this?

Comment: When you say control do you mean the entire simulation? or to alter settings? You can change any setting easily, while the simulation must be run based on settings. [Blenders api reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) describes all the data in blender, which simulation do you want to run?